# Access Third Party Root Certification Authorities of Windows from Java

Tags: java, windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I am trying to get the trusted certificates from Windows programatically within Java. I am already able to get the following `Personal` and `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` which can also be found in `Certlm` as shown below:

[image]

```java
import java.security.KeyStore;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // get Trusted Root Certification Authorities
        KeyStore root = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
        root.load(null, null);

        // get Personal
        KeyStore my = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
        my.load(null, null);
    }
    
}
```

However I am not able to get `Third Party Root Certification Authorities`. Any idea if there is another special keystore available like the others to get access to those certificates or a different mechanisme to obtain those certificates?